# MySQL query or Jasper to extrapolate a column value calculated on current and next column values

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I have a MySQL query that returns these values:

```
+------------+-------+
| transcount | users |
+------------+-------+
|        118 |     2 |
|        240 |     4 |
|        480 |     8 |
+------------+-------+
```

This is a count of transactions at each user level. The users field is ordered asc.

I need to produce a report that shows the step increase in transcount we should get as the number of users increases in a linear scaling system. For example, at 2 users we got 118 transactions and in a linear scaling system at 4 users we should get 236 transcount, (4 / 2 x 118 transactions.) And then at 8 users we should get 480 transcount (8 / 4 x 240 transcount).

The first row is always the same value. The final report should look like this:

```
+------------+-------+-------------------------|
| transcount | users | Count_at_linear_scaling |
+------------+-------+-------------------------|
|        118 |     2 |                     118 |
|        240 |     4 |                     236 |
|        480 |     8 |                     480 |
+------------+-------+-------------------------|
```

I could do this either in SQL or in a Jasper chart. Which do you recommend? How do I do this in MySQL and Jasper?

Answer (score 1):

Jim from Jasper Support offer:

Hi, try the methods in this link, it is pretty similar to what you need.
http://jasperforge.org/plugins/mwiki/index.php/Jasperserver/Creating_A_Percent_Of_Field
Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the better solution. I needed to implement a buck brigade pattern for each row of results data. Using two variables - named in and out - I can store the previous row's value in the variable out, and store the new row's value in the variable in. The trick is to tell Jasper to use "Auto" evaluation time for in and "Now" evaluation time for out. For example:

```
<variable name="in" class="java.lang.Long" resetType="None" calculation="System">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{out}]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="out" class="java.lang.Long" resetType="None">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{Y_VALUE}]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{Y_VALUE}]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

and

```
<detail>
    <band height="35">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="3" y="0" width="46" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{controllers_users}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="67" y="0" width="58" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Y_VALUE}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Auto">
            <reportElement x="148" y="0" width="44" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{in}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="203" y="0" width="44" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{out}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

-Frank